# MvvmCross using Xamarin newly supported Async

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

Now Xamarin officialy supports the new C# 5 Async keywords async and await, how could we use them in an MvvmCross project using PCL and what do we need to reference/install (Task<>, what PCL profile etc.)

regards,

Arthur

Comment: PCL scenario is a little hazy right now, with Xamarin's latest release they have released some new profiles which are not compatible with Mvvmcross, so I have heard. I suggest you wait for sometime for the situation to resolve.

Comment: What have you tried? PCL profiles for .NET 4.5 / Windows Store should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Async/await is available in PCL's targeting .NET 4.5 and Windows Phone 8 and Windows Store projects. This means something like Profile78 could be useful.

However, if you need to target Windows Phone 7 you will need to work your way around the licensing issues that come with using Microsoft.BCL, as it is only allowed to use that on Microsoft platforms. There is [Async Bridge from this years Build](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=8a7fb4a4b32fb2c9&id=8A7FB4A4B32FB2C9!426&authkey=!AGfvvhOyBfCdYJg) conference, by Daniel Plaisted, which could help. I've had it working in my Xamarin projects.